# Compile Clojure using Maven

Tags: maven, clojure, compilation, build-process

What is the preferred way to *compile* Clojure using Maven?

In my particular situation I have a set of Clojure `.clj` files that I would like to be AOT-compiled to `.class` files during the Maven compilation phase, and included in the resulting `.jar`.

Comment: Are you compiling clojure.core or wanting an uber jar containing clojure.core and your code?

Comment: I'm writing a library that I'm looking to pre-compile (so it is neither clojure.core itself or an uberjar, just a regular module of library code)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this Maven plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin) to compile clojure code.

Comment: thanks Ankur - any idea how to configure it to AOT compile a specific set of `.clj` files?